# Boundedness in $H^1(\Omega) $ and tightness

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded subset of $\Bbb R^d$. And let $ (u_n)_n$ be a bounded sequence of the Sobolev space $H^1(\Omega)$.

Question: Can  we say that $ (u_n)_n$  is tight in $L^2(\Omega)$ namely: For very $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a compact set $K_\varepsilon\subset \Omega$ such that $$ \sup_{n}\int_{\Omega\setminus K_\varepsilon }|u_n(x)|^2dx<\varepsilon$$

I failed to find a counter example. Any help or reference in which I can find related topic is welcome.

Comment: Do you know the compact embedding of Sobolev spaces?

Comment: Yes The Reillich-Kondrakov theorem ?

Comment: Yes, $u_n$ is a convergent sequence in $L^2$, thus $\| u_n \|_{L^2} \le \| u_n - u_m\|_{L^2} + \| u_m\|_{L^2}$ for all $n\ge m$. The first term on the right hand side can be made arbitrary small. So you need only to deal with finitely many terms.

Comment: The compact embedding implies the convergence of a subsequence or???

Comment: Yes, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The Sobolev embedding gives that

$$ \| u_n\|_{L^p} \le C \| u_n\|_{H^1},$$

where $p = 2^*>2$ when $d \ge 3$ and is any $p >2$ when $d=1, 2$. Thus we have

$$ \int_{\Omega\setminus K} |u_n|^2 \le \left( \int_{\Omega\setminus K} |u_n|^p\right)^{2/p} \big(\operatorname{Vol} (\Omega \setminus K)\big)^{1/q}\le C_1 \big(\operatorname{Vol} (\Omega \setminus K)\big)^{1/q}$$

for any set $K$. Now for any $\epsilon >0$, choose $K_\epsilon$ so that

$$C_1 \big(\operatorname{Vol} (\Omega \setminus K_\epsilon)\big)^{1/q}<\epsilon$$

and you are done.

Comment: Ok this  fantastic when $\Omega $ is a regular domain